# Unselected value from a group by query to subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to provide an unselected set of values from a group by query to a subquery

Like

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 154 |
| 2 | a | 845 |
| 3 | b | 558 |
| 4 | c | 88 |

If I do

```
SELECT col_2, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tb_1 GROUP BY col_2
```

I get:

| col_2 | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |

Here, the first row contains 2 col_3 values [154, 845]. I want to pass these values to a subquery in the select part and get a result. Like:

```
SELECT col_2
     , (SELECT SUM(balance) FROM accounts WHERE id IN col_3) AS combined_balance 
  FROM tb_1
```

So the final output would look like

| col_2 | balance |
| --- | --- |
| a | 150 |
| b | 200 |
| c | 180 |

If the accounts table look like

| id | balance |
| --- | --- |
| 154 | 100 |
| 846 | 50 |
| 558 | 200 |
| 88 | 180 |

Comment: Please add your desired outcome. AND where did id and balance come from??

Comment: id would be a column in the accounts table. col_3 refers to that ID (FK). What I actually want to do is that I want to pass the values of a non-grouped column (that means that column would contain different values within the column) to a subquery.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `an unselected set of values`? Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong simply join the tables and aggregate the values

```
select col2,sum(balance) 
from tb_1
join accounts a on a.id = tb_1.col3
group by col2;
```